# Why consciousness is lost immediately when heart stops beating?

Tags: brain, breathing, death, heartbeat, unconsciousness

When heart stops beating - consciousness is lost in seconds. It is explained that it is due to the drop of blood pressure in brain veins. However, by my understanding - that should only make brain cells to starve of oxygen and make them die only in minutes(5+) and in the mean-time consciousness should continue all that time. Why that does not happen?

Comment: You're equating unconsciousness with brain death, and that's incorrect. Consciousness can be lost for many reasons even when the brain is perfectly healthy, which should tell you that consciousness is a much more fragile thing than brain death.